# Add different types of the same probe in Smokeping

Tags: smokeping

How do you add different probes of the same type in Smokeping?

My initial attempt:

```
+ FPing
binary=/usr/sbin/fping

+ FPing2
binary=/usr/sbin/fping
sourceaddress=192.168.1.2
```

Yielded:

```
$ smokeping check
require Smokeping::probes::FPing2 failed: Can't locate Smokeping/probes/FPing2.pm in @INC (@INC contains: .. /usr/share/smokeping /root/perl5/lib/perl5 /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at (eval 22) line 2, <$fh> line 111.
```

I'm sure I'm overlooking something obvious!

I have consulted the Probe documentation here https://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/probe/index.en.html, to no avail and I'm sure that something so trivial shouldn't require a new module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I was overlooking something obvious - the "Probe" section of the "Config" page in the documentation here: https://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/doc/smokeping_config.en.html#___top

```
+ FPing
binary = /usr/sbin/fping

++ FPingA
sourceaddress = 192.168.1.2

++ FPingB
sourceaddress = 192.168.1.3

# Further down under Targets:
probe=FPingA
```

SImple as that!

Comment: The BIG thing missing here, and in the documentation is:  "if you want two FPing probes, *both* must be Children of FPing ..."  - https://lists.oetiker.ch/pipermail/smokeping-users/2016-September/005903.html   So in the example Config given in the answer here, only FPingA and FPingB can be specified as a probe= value.

Answer (score -1):

Copy the probe file under another name, in the same direcotory (/SMOLKEDIR/lib/Smokeping/probes)

eg: cp EchoPing.pm EhoPing2.pm

open EchoPing2.pm with any text editor,
make obvious changes
(eg: at the first line change Smokeping::probes:EchoPing whit Smokeping::probes:EchoPing2
and so on.

Use both EchoPing and EchoPing2 in the same mannner in the RTT file

Comment: Thanks for the attempt - and this was my first thought too - but this is not portable - as you'd have to ship changes with any config files... also, the existing configuration files support this quite elegantly.